# Ng-bind still renders html

Tags: angularjs

I am getting json data from a 3rd party. Some of it renders ok using ng-bind in which it converts and renders html code.

But with others it does not. It's like it need to ng-bind it again.

I have tried running it through a function or filter

```
$scope.trustedHtml = function (plainText) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(plainText);
    }

ng-bind-html="trustedHtml(hotelDetails.roomInformation)"
```

I have also tried a filter in my app

```
.filter("to_trusted", ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return function(htmlCode){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
  }
}]);
```

But both of these do not work(if i'm doing somethng wrong). How can I get html to render correctly on my page?

**This is what i'm getting back from the API**

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Know Before You Go&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt;&lt;ul&gt; &lt;li&gt;
```

**This is what I am getting using ng-bing-html and the same as running it through the function**

```
<p><b>Know Before You Go</b> <br /><ul> <li>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K1eMoKJQg3S8sY4aWbXs?p=preview)

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with an example of data you received?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting this problem because of either of these 3 reasons.

**1. Did you install bower sanitize?**

> If not install it using
>   **bower install angular-sanitize**
>   . (And don't forget to include it in your HTML)

**2.  Did you inject sanitize in your controller?**

> If not inject it inyour controller

```
var app = angular.module(app,'ngSanitize');
```

**3. Did you use {{}} ?**

> You'll not see the output if you have used {{}}. Instead use

```
 <div ng-bind-html="hotelDetails.roomInformation"></div>
```

Comment: Bower sanitize is installed, I have injected it into my app rather than the controller and I am not using {{}}

Comment: A JsFiddle/Plunker would be helpful to debug.